# @Input variable gets filled on HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

In my `app.component.ts` I call a function from a service that returns the result of a HTTP request:

```
questions: QuestionBase<any>[];
constructor(service: QuestionService) {
    this.questions = service.getQuestions().subscribe(val => console.log(val)); //gets logged after the other console log below
}
```

In the child component this `questions` array is processed further:

```
@Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private qcs: QuestionControlService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("onInit", this.questions); //called before questions is filled
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
}
```

My problem is now that the `toFormGroup` Function in `ngOnInit` is called too early when the HTTP request hasn't finished. I'm not used to Observables. How could I call the function after the HTTP request in `getQuestions` has finished. I already tried `ngOnChanges` but it gets called even before `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a condition by checking in the `ngOnChanges` if questions have values before doing anything with them:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if(questions && questions.length) {
     this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
  }
}
```

Comment: @n00dl3 Hahhah, thanks! :D she has a sister as well, she's also cute with being cross-eyed and almost completely blind :P Maybe you seen the pic, was my last profile pic.. I thought she needed a break from representing me :D http://imgur.com/a/m2s0d

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to assign the value to questions inside the subscribe() call:

```
service.getQuestions().subscribe(val => this.questions=val);
```

Also, in the child component, you can implement `ngOnChanges()` and skip the very first binding to the `@Input()` property when the value is still null.The `SimpleChange` class has a boolean property `firstChange`.

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: {[key: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    if (!changes.questions.firstChange){
         this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);}

  }
```

Comment: I get errors: ',' expected, Cannot find name 'key', Property 'questions' does not exist on type '[any, string]'

Comment: Note that it might be better to check that `questions` is defined or not instead of checking for first change if the component is used elsewhere, without `questions` being populated asynchronously.

Comment: this plus what @n00dl3 is what I suggested in my [earlier reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43607331/222955)

Answer (score 0):

You can call toFormGroup in an ngOnChanges. And, if you need to, only call toFormGroup when questions gets its first value. I'm on mobile right now so I cannot provide a code sample.

Comment: I already tried to call in `ngOnChange` instead of `ngOnInit` but it is still called before this line: `this.questions = service.getQuestions().subscribe(val => console.log(val));` is logged so `questions` array is empty and I get errors.

Comment: You could detect if it's the first change or that the array isn't empty in the ngOnChanges